# asp.net mvc 4.0 linq query with datetime field returns something like this /Date(1391600738810)/

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I have this class called ProcessoCliente, this class is a modelview, I use it to display some values on a IgniteUI igGrid.

Here is the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using LicenciamentoMVC.Models;

namespace LicenciamentoMVC.ModelsView
{
public class ProcessoCliente
{
    public int IDProcesso { get; set; }
    public string NomeCliente { get; set; }

    public DateTime DataInserido { get; set; }
    public int Estado { get; set; }
}
public class ProcessoModel
{
    private static ProcessoCliente entity;
    public static IQueryable<ProcessoCliente> GetListaProcessosClientes()
    {
        MvcApplication1Context db = new MvcApplication1Context();

        var processos =  (from p in db.Processos
                         join c in db.Clientes on p.IDCliente equals c.IDCliente
                          orderby p.IDProcesso descending
                         select new ProcessoCliente { IDProcesso = p.IDProcesso, NomeCliente = c.Nome, DataInserido = p.DataInserido , Estado=p.Estado});


        return processos.AsQueryable<ProcessoCliente>();
    }

}
}
```

The problem is the datetime field that its returning as /Date(1391600738810)/, and it displays as this.
How can I convert through linq query to get a datetime value as yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss..2014-02-05 12:00:00?
And can anyone tell me why this happens and what type is this..
According to sql server the data stored is in the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss..

this is the code the grid in the view:

```
  @( Html.Infragistics().Grid<LicenciamentoMVC.ModelsView.ProcessoCliente>()

    .Caption("Processos")
    .ID("grid1")
    .DefaultColumnWidth("200px")
    .PrimaryKey("IDProcesso")
    .Columns(column =>
    {

        column.For(x =>x.NomeCliente).DataType("string").HeaderText("Nome do Cliente").Width("50%");
        column.For(x => x.DataInserido).DataType("DateTime").HeaderText("Data de Criação do Processo").Width("25%");
        column.For(x => x.NomeCliente).DataType("int").HeaderText("Estado").Width("25%");

        column.For(x => x.IDProcesso).DataType("int").Width("0%");




    })
    .Features(features =>
    {
        features.Paging().PageSize(20).PrevPageLabelText("Previous").NextPageLabelText("NEXT");
        features.Sorting().Mode(SortingMode.Single).ColumnSettings(settings =>
        {
            settings.ColumnSetting().ColumnKey("NomeCliente").AllowSorting(true);

        });
        features.Selection().MultipleSelection(false).Mode(SelectionMode.Row);
        features.Filtering().Mode(FilterMode.Simple);
        features.Updating()
               .EnableAddRow(false)
               .EnableDeleteRow(true)
               .EditMode(GridEditMode.None);




    })
    .DataSourceUrl(Url.Action("ListarProcessos"))    
    .UpdateUrl(Url.Action("DeleteProcessos"))        
   .AutofitLastColumn(false)
   .Width("100%")
    .AutoGenerateColumns(false)
    .DataBind()
    .Render()
    )
```

and here is the code for the controller action:

```
 [GridDataSourceAction]
    public ActionResult ListarProcessos()
    {
        return View(LicenciamentoMVC.ModelsView.ProcessoModel.GetListaProcessosClientes());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change in you class like this

```
public string DataInseridoString { 
   get 
    {
         if(this.DataInserido!=null)
             retrun   this.DataInserido.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss");
         else
             return string.Empty;
    }
 }
```

And bind this property to your front end

---

there is nothing realted to linq I think you need to fromate you date by using tostring and forate string

```
theDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss")
```

Comment: but where can i do that...i alredy tryed on listarProcessoCliente, on the linq expression DataInserida=p.DataInseridaToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss"); and int he declaration of the igGrid  column.For(x => x.DataInserido.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss").DataType("string").HeaderText("Data de Criação do Processo").Width("25%"); and nothing works

Comment: @HugoSilva - you can do it in linq query ...and change data type of variable to string which is accepting value

Comment: it gives me erros on the line column.For(x => x.DataInserido.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss").DataType("string").HeaderText("Data de Criação do Processo").Width("25%"); nullreferenceexception

Comment: you can try   column.For(x => x.DataInserido!=null ?  x.DataInserido.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss") : string.Empty)... because there might be issue because of property having null value ..

Comment: The same error..  the line --->column.For(x => x.DataInserido != null ? x.DataInserido.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss") : string.Empty).DataType("string").HeaderText("Data de Criação do Processo").Width("25%");

Comment: i am thinking on creating an unbound column and try to convert them in  jquery function..

Answer (score 0):

Are you receiving the date through a JSON web service somewhere? If you're parsing the JSON yourself (for some reason), you're going to get the kind of string you got. So, to fix this, either consume the web service properly (.NET can handle the deserialization just fine on its own), or you have to parse the date out of it.

That means - get the numeric value inside. Then, use this snippet:

```
new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds(extractedValue);
```

And you should get the correct DateTime :)

Answer (score 0):

So , after a bit of search i manage to find a solution...
here goes the way i did it..
the changes needed were made on the model:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using LicenciamentoMVC.Models;

 namespace LicenciamentoMVC.ModelsView
{
public class ProcessoCliente
{
    public int IDProcesso { get; set; }
    public string NomeCliente { get; set; }

    public string  DataInserido { get; set; }
    public int Estado { get; set; }
}

public class ProcessoModel
{
    private static ProcessoCliente entity;
    public static IQueryable<ProcessoCliente> GetListaProcessosClientes()
    {
        MvcApplication1Context db = new MvcApplication1Context();

        var processos =  (from p in db.Processos
                         join c in db.Clientes on p.IDCliente equals c.IDCliente
                          orderby p.IDProcesso descending
                          select new { IDProcesso = p.IDProcesso, NomeCliente = c.Nome, DataInserido = p.DataInserido, Estado = p.Estado }).ToList().Select(c => new ProcessoCliente
                          {
                              IDProcesso = c.IDProcesso,
                              NomeCliente = c.NomeCliente,
                              DataInserido = c.DataInserido.ToString(),
                              Estado=c.Estado
                          });


        return processos.AsQueryable<ProcessoCliente>();
    }

}
}
```

Thanks everyone